# Minimum number of digit changes to get two arrays to have the same value. Please solve in R programming

Tags: r, arrays, comparison

I am pretty new to coding and I'm trying my best, but after hours and hours of research i still cant figure this out. I'm trying to make these two separate arrays the same with the minimum number of moves. I can only ++ or -- one number at a time.

This is the challenge:

No reordering of the digits is allowed For example, consider two arrays: Andrea's [123, 543] and Maria's [321, 279]. For the first digit, Andrea can increment the 1 twice to achieve 3. The 2's are equal already. Finally, she decrements her 3 twice to equal 1. It took 4 moves to reach her goal. For the second integer, she decrements 5 three times, increments 4 three times and 3 six times. It took 12 moves to convert the second array element. In total, it took 16 moves to convert both values comprising the complete array.

```
# Complete the 'minimumMoves' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER_ARRAY a
#  2. INTEGER_ARRAY m
#

minimumMoves <- function(a, m) {
    # Write your code here

}
stdin <- file('stdin')
open(stdin)

fptr <- file(Sys.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"))
open(fptr, open = "w")

aCount <- as.integer(trimws(readLines(stdin, n = 1, warn = FALSE), which = "both"))
a <- readLines(stdin, n = aCount, warn = FALSE)
a <- trimws(a, which = "both")
a <- as.integer(a)

mCount <- as.integer(trimws(readLines(stdin, n = 1, warn = FALSE), which = "both"))
m <- readLines(stdin, n = mCount, warn = FALSE)
m <- trimws(m, which = "both")
m <- as.integer(m)

`enter code here`result <- minimumMoves(a, m)

`enter code here`writeLines(as.character(result), con = fptr)

    enter code here

close(stdin)
close(fptr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

minimumMoves <- function(a, m) {
  n = length(a)
  rlt = numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x = as.numeric(unlist(str_split(a[i], "")))
    y = as.numeric(unlist(str_split(m[i], "")))
    rlt[i] = sum(abs(x - y))
  }
  sum(rlt)
}

a = c(123,543)
m = c(321,279)
minimumMoves(a, m)
# [1]  16
```

Comment: Getting below error and no output

Error in str_split(a[i], "") : could not find function "str_split"
Calls: minimumMoves -> unlist
Execution halted

Comment: `library(stringr)`

Comment: one test case below got passed but remaining are failing

1
2468
1
8642

Comment: 0 16， is'nt it？

Comment: I need one output which is 16 only. Now i am getting two ouputs I need sum of that. How to do that? Please help.

Comment: Oh，the last  line of fucntion use `sum(rlt)`